# Getters and Setters in Lombok when serializing

Tags: java, json, serialization, lombok, jsonserializer

I have this inner class defined in a service

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class HostelIntegrationTest  {


    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    static class User {
        String property1;
        Instant property2;
        Integer property3;
    }
```

but when I serialize the class

```
User user = User.builder().property1("property1").property2(Instant.now()).property3(5).build();
        JSONSerializer.toJSON(user))
```

I got this error:

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'property1' has no getter method in class..
```

Comment: You can drop most of your annotations there: `@Data` includes `@Getter`, `@Setter`, `@EqualsAndHashCode` and in most cases `@NoArgsConstructor`... Just saying...

Comment: You can Remove  `@ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter @Setter and @RequiredArgsConstructor` Because it is included in `@Data`

Comment: try `public static class User {`

Comment: Read https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder